# Flutter: How do I change theme brightness at runtime?

Tags: flutter, material-design

I have a `MaterialApp` with a `ThemeData` that is initially set to `Brightness.light`.  I'd like to switch the brightness to `Brightness.dark` at runtime, but when I make that change, only the status bar changes - none of the Flutter widgets actually change their brightness.

How can this behavior be achieved?

To change the `ThemeData` at runtime, I've created the following `StatefulWidget` that wraps my `MaterialApp` and rebuilds it whenever the theme changes:

```
final ThemeData appTheme = ThemeData(
  brightness: Brightness.light,
);

class ThemeChanger extends StatefulWidget {
  static ThemeChangerState of (BuildContext context) {
    return context.ancestorStateOfType(TypeMatcher<ThemeChangerState>());
  }

  ThemeChanger({
    this.childBuilder,
  });

  final Widget Function(BuildContext, ThemeData) childBuilder;

  @override
  ThemeChangerState createState() => ThemeChangerState();
}

class ThemeChangerState extends State<ThemeChanger> {
  Brightness _brightness = Brightness.light;

  set brightness(Brightness brightness) {
    setState(() {
      _brightness = brightness;
    });
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return widget.childBuilder(
      context,
      appTheme.copyWith(
        brightness: _brightness
      ),
    );
  }
}

// Then in main.dart
void main() => runApp(MyApp());

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return DemoTheme(
      childBuilder: (BuildContext context, ThemeData theme) {
        return MaterialApp(
          title: 'Materially Better',
          theme: theme,
          routes: {
            '/': (BuildContext context) {
              return LoginScreen();
            },
            'home': (BuildContext context) {
              return MainScreen();
            }
          },
          debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
        );
      },
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 4):

The issue is that `ThemeData` uses its `brightness` value in the constructor to synthesize a number of other colors, but those colors are not re-calculated when `ThemeData` is mutated. Therefore, the solution is to instantiate an entirely new `ThemeData` rather than use `appTheme.copyWith(...)`.

Change this:

```
appTheme.copyWith(
  brightness: _brightness,
),
```

To this:

```
ThemeData(
  brightness: _brightness,
),
```

Comment: Actually `copyWith` instantiates `new` instance of class. Just see the code of method.

Answer (score 3):

My solution is the following:

1. Define a variable in `main.dart` for the brightness and a function that changes the state.
2. Pass the function to a class and then call it wherever you need.

```
//main.dart
class _MyAppState extends State<MyApp> {
  Brightness _brightness = Brightness.light;

  void _changeBrightness(Brightness newBrightness) {
    setState(() {
      _brightness = newBrightness;
    });
  }

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    WidgetsBinding.instance.addPostFrameCallback((_) {
      //PASSING THE FUNCTION AS PARAMETER
      Util.changeBrightness = _changeBrightness;
    });
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Your app title',
      theme: ThemeData(
        primaryColor: const Color(0xFFb30047),
        brightness: _brightness,
        primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
        accentColor: Colors.white,
        /// ...and so on
```

In the `Util` class

```
class Util {
   static Brightness currentBrightness = Brightness.light;
   static Function changeBrightness;
   // ...further implementations
```

And then call it when you need. In my case, a switch change in the settings screen:

```
darkModeChanged(bool newValue) {
   Preferences.setBool('darkMode', newValue);
   setState(() {
     _darkMode = newValue;
     Util.currentBrightness = _darkMode ? Brightness.dark : Brightness.light;        
     Util.changeBrightness(Util.currentBrightness);
   });
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can check out the following library: https://github.com/Norbert515/dynamic_theme

It allows you to change the entire theme data or brightness of your app dynamically at runtime.

Answer (score -1):

You can change the theme at runtime with ThemeBuilder :

```js
setState(() {
  ThemeBuilder.of(context).changeTheme();
});
```

Comment: What is `ThemeBuilder`? That's not included in Flutter itself, right?