# Flutter how to set brightness?

Tags: android, ios, flutter, mobile

In Flutter, How to set maximum brightness of iOS & android devices when first load? and I tried some dart, but it is not working.

Flutter version: 2.5.3

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54139924/flutter-how-do-i-change-theme-brightness-at-runtime#:~:text=Define%20a%20variable%20in%20main,call%20it%20wherever%20you%20need.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**UPDATE:**

you can set brightness with this dependency [screen_brightness](https://pub.dev/packages/screen_brightness).

this will help you to get the details of brightness also you can set it manually.

Moreover, screen brightness wouldn't change in emulator. You need a real device to test it out.

Comment: flutter >2.5 screen dart is  deprecated. I tried before.

Comment: you can try with this library also https://pub.dev/packages/screen_brightness

Comment: Because screen_brightness >=0.1.3 depends on screen_brightness_platform_interface ^0.0.3 which depends on plugin_platform_interface ^2.0.2, screen_brightness >=0.1.3 requires plugin_platform_interface ^2.0.2

Comment: I got some errors above.

Comment: can you please change the version of **screen_brightness ^0.0.3** as your dependency conflicting

Comment: After changed to 0.0.3, it works, but I got another program error.

Comment: like what kind of error?

Comment: ScreenBrightness.onCurrentBrightnessChanged function is highlighted in red and also ScreenBrightness() function not found~example code: https://pub.dev/packages/screen_brightness/example

Comment: you have to go through this doc: https://pub.dev/packages/screen_brightness/versions/0.0.3

Comment: The example code some views are missing, blank_page.dart, controller_page.dart, home_page.dart, route_aware_page.dart

Comment: my friend that is just example to adjust the brightness you just need this code
=>
    Future<void> setBrightness(double brightness) async {
      try {
        await ScreenBrightness.setScreenBrightness(brightness);
      } catch (e) {
        print(e);
        throw 'Failed to set brightness';
      }
    }

Comment: Well, If it is that case, I try already called setBrightness(1.0) when page load, but tested, it is not working for me.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/241164/discussion-between-jay-gadariya-and-chanrlc).